# Mudar o arquivo ( jpeg , gif ou swf ) de acordo com tamanho de tela?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tenho um Site em PHP e nele possui um campo para anúncios publicitários ( Onde eu posso colar códigos )

Como é um site que se redimensiona eu não faço ideia de como fazer um código HTML ou JAVA usar diferentes imagens para o mesmo espaço publicitário ( vários arquivos para diferentes dimensões - Pc ou Mobile  )

Por exemplo :

No Campo X eu poder usar ( colar )  um código
que me permita usar dois arquivos
para diferentes dimensões

por exemplo:

Dimensão 230x90 px   para Celular
Dimensão 978x90 px   para PC

alguém pode me ajudar ?
ficarei muito grato kkkkkkkkk

encontrei vários códigos, mas nao consegui

Comment: acho que essa idéia vai funcionar para vc  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57828/mudar-banner-de-acordo-com-tamanho-de-tela

Comment: Eu vi aqui, porém nao consegui entender onde direciono os arquivos nesses códigos.

Comment: Há uma infinidade de tamanhos de tela, não seria melhor já detectar se é mobile ou não e inserir o arquivo correspondente?

Comment: isso !!!  pq eu quero falar td para ser entendido e acabo é atrapalhando.

busco um código que me ajude nisso, que ao acessar no celular ele busque o arquivo x   

e ao acessar no pc ele busque o arquivo y

Comment: seria mais ou menos isso 
mas não imagino como chamar ou dizer qual arquivo ele deve chamar quando tiver nessa dimensão.

@media(max-width: 500px){
    .texto{
        font-size: 10px;
        color: black;
    }
   }

ignore o código, apenas um exemplo

Comment: uai, a pergunta é mudar ( jpeg , gif ou swf ) de acordo com tamanho de tela, e no comentário trata-se de um CSS

Comment: sim mudar, independente de como fazer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar imagens como *background* em divs e usar *media-query* para ajustar, um exemplo se tiver duas imagens:

```
<style>
.banner-1 {
    background: url(images/normal/banner1.jpg);
    display: inline-block;
    width: 978px;
    height: 90px;
}

.banner-2 {
    background: url(images/normal/banner2.jpg);
    display: inline-block;
    width: 500px;
    height: 50px;
}

@media (max-width: 420px) {
   .banner-1 {
        background-image: url(images/celular/banner1.jpg);
        width: 230px;
   }
   .banner-2 {
        background-image: url(images/celular/banner2.jpg);
        width: 100px;
        height: 10px;
   }
}
</style>

<div class="banner-1"></div>
<div class="banner-2"></div>
```

Ajuste o `@media (max-width: 420px)` para o que achar adequado para a tela dos celulares, já o `swf` não teria como trocar, mas geralmente os próprios swf podem ser expanciveis, então bastaria adicionar ele `width: 100%;` para ajustar ao elemento DIV que recebe o `width:` e `height` da media-query por exemplo, no entanto devo lhe alertar que Google Chrome e Firefox já bloqueiam por padrão arquivos `swf` (creio que tenha como ativar ou ainda tem o **click to play**, mas é algo que realmente vai só funcionar dependendo do usuário, flash já não é um bom caminho faz tempo)

Comment: vou testar aqui, mas vi que vc entendeu o que busco.

Comment: OBRIGADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO !!

Comment: @jhonatansantos por nada, e seja bem vindo a nossa comunidade.

Answer (score 1):

Veja se atende, vai detectar se é mobile e chamar um arquivo e caso contrário chama outro arquivo

```
function isMobile(){
    var a = navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera;
    if(/android|avantgo|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|ip(hone|od|ad)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile|o2|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|smartphone|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce; (iemobile|ppc)|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\-|e\/|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\-|2|g)|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a))
        return true;    
    else
        return false;
}

if(isMobile()){
    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mobile.css" />');
}else{
    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="desktop.css" />');
}
```

.No    `document.write` pode colocar o que desejar, uma imagem, chamada de arquivo css, etc... ou até mesmo um HTML inteiro.

```
document.write('<img src="http://site/aaa.jpg">');
```

Comment: vou testar e te aviso , mas desde ja agradeço pela ajuda man

Comment: obrigado cara deu certo